# Как правильно сказать: Купалу или Купала?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фольклор

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно сказать: "Местные жители отмечают Купалу" или "Местные жители отмечают Купала"?

Answer (score 1):

Купалу.
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0
Название праздника и имя божества - Купала или Купало. Если мы поставим в винительный падеж слово Купала, получим Купалу. Если Купало - то в вин. падеже это будет Купало.
Следовательно, выражение "отмечать Купал" - невозможно, потому что слова Купал нет.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше сказать : Местные жители отмечают праздник Ивана Купалы (Ивана Травника, Иванов день)

Answer (score 0):

Формально - одинаково возможны три варианта.
Если от "(Иван) Купала" - то "отмечают (Ивана) Купалу".
Если от "(Иван) Купала" - то "отмечают (Ивана) Купалу" - по своременным правилам,
И "отмечают (Ивана) Купала" по историческим или по украинскому образцу.

Сложность возникает во втором случае, поскольку в современном русском языке одушевлённые существительные на "-о" вышли из употребления и навык их склонения утерян.   
Следует ещё отметить, что дыа последних варианта неразличимы фонетически (в русском), что тоже не способствует применению третьего варианта.